# How to convert List<Integer> into JSONArray of Integers, using stream() method in Java

Tags: java, arrays, java-stream

I'm trying to find best way to convert List of Integers to JSONArray of org.json.JSONArray library for API call. For that purpose I'm trying to implement stream() methods of Java 8.

Given

```
List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<>();

ids.add(1);

ids.add(2);

ids.add(3);
```

Needed JSONArray object

```
JSONArray ids = [1,2,3]
```

with using stream() method in Java.

Comment: Why do you need to use the stream method?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily without using streams by using the constructor of the `JSONArray` class which accepts a `Collection`:

```
List<Integer> ids = List.of(1, 2, 3);
JSONArray json = new JSONArray(ids);
```

If you have to use streams for some reason:

```
List<Integer> ids = List.of(1, 2, 3);
JSONArray json = new JSONArray();
ids.stream().forEach(json::put);
```

As pointed out by Alexander Ivanchenko in the comments however, you should [avoid doing this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#SideEffects).

Comment: You don't need to create a stream, instead you can invoke `forEach()` on a list. It will be both cleaner and cheaper.

Comment: I am aware, but the poster also specifically asked for an implementation using a `stream` which is why I added an alternative including it.

Comment: But the fact that the way in which you are advising to use streams in **not encouraged** by the [API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#SideEffects) still remains. Take a look at the code examples in the part dedicated to side-effects.

Comment: I was not trying to advise to use them but only wanted to provide a solution that fits the posters requirement of using a `stream`, sorry if this was unclear. I have added a note regarding what you pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mutable reduction with [`collect()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.BiConsumer,java.util.function.BiConsumer)).

***Note***, that usage of streams is justifiable only if you need to filter or change some values along the way, otherwise it'll be an unnecessary complication of the code.

```
List<String> source = List.of("1", "2", "3");

JSONArray result =
    source.stream()
          .map(str -> str.concat(".0"))
          .collect(
              JSONArray::new,
              JSONArray::put,
              JSONArray::putAll);
    
System.out.println(result);
```

**Output**

```
["1.0","2.0","3.0"]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Naive solution:**
A naive solution is to iterate over the given set and copy each encountered element in the Integer array one by one.

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
Integer[] array = new Integer[set.size()];
 
int k = 0;
for (Integer i: set) {
    array[k++] = i;
}
 
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

**Using Set.toArray() method:**
Set interface provides the `toArray()` method that returns an `Object` array containing the elements of the set.

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
Object[] array = set.toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```